# React Native - stack elements vertically, relatively?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

Alright, what Im trying to achieve is this, where all the elements are "bottom justified" and would move up/down depending on the height of the `cardContainer` element, and so on:

[image]

Ive achieved this with `position: absolute` and the `react-native-responsive-screen` plugin, but am concerned that this is not scaleable/the best way to achieve this.

```
container: { flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      color: 'white'
    },
      textWrapper: {
        height: hp('70%'), // 70% of height device screen
        width: wp('80%'),   // 80% of width device screen
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        zIndex: 3, // works on ios
        elevation: 3,
        position: 'absolute'
      },
      //Main containers --------------------
      cardContainer: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        height: hp('62%'),
        width: wp('100%'),
        padding: 10,
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 0
      },
      topTextContainer: {
        color: 'white',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: hp('4.8%'),
        height: hp('22%'),
        width: wp('100%'),
        position: 'absolute',
        top: hp('20%'),
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 20,
        paddingLeft: wp('15%'),
        paddingRight: wp('15%'),
      },
      topBarContainer: {
        color: 'white',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontFamily: 'SequelSans-BlackDisp',
        height: hp('10%'),
        width: wp('100%'),
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        opacity: 0.6,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },

  <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.textWrapper}>
              <Text style={styles.splashTxt}>COLOR</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.topBarContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.topText_Body}>Welcome back, Person</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.topTextContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.topText_Head}>Take the Quiz</Text>
                <Text style={styles.topText_Body}>Take a deep dive into the background some more background text goes here goes here.</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
```

How can I achieve this positioning relatively?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the flex property
Here's a great write up https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox.html

Visually, it looks like the relationship is 1:3:5 between the vertical views.

```
.textWrapper {
flex: 1;

}
.topBarContainer{
 flex: 3;
}
.topTextContainer{
 flex: 5;
}
```